# cannot import graphql node package using import keyword

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

Can someone please explain to me ?

Each time I try to import the `graphql` node package using the `import` keyword, the imported module is read as undefined but if require is used, the module gets imported.
But other node packages works fine with `import` keyword.

Here is what I mean:

```
import graphql from 'graphql';
// console.log(graphql) ---> undefined

const graphql = require('graphql');
// console.log(graphql) ---> {graphql: ......}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be imported as named import:

```
import { graphql } from 'graphql';
```

The difference with other Node packages is that `graphql` has native ES module entry point (index.mjs) that is used when it's imported as ES module. Most packages have only CommonJS entry points (e.g. index.js), module interoperability makes them imported as default import when they are imported as ES modules.

Comment: Thanks @estus, 
That did work fine.
I had to use `require`